# Split messages by routing key in mass transit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'd like to send a message to an appropriate queue based on the routing key. Starting from the producer app, my code (the relevant parts) is:

```
var options = serviceProvider
    .GetService<IConfiguration>()
    .GetOptions<RabbitMqProducerOptions>("RabbitMqProducer");

foreach (var option in options?.Endpoints)
{
    var method = typeof(EndpointConvention).GetMethod("Map", new[] { typeof(Uri) });
    var type = Assembly.Load(option.Assembly).GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == option.Type);
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type });

    genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { new Uri($"{options.Address}/{option.Name}") });
}

Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => {
    cfg.Host(options.Address);
    cfg.Send<CreateProducts>(x => x.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(context => context.Message.Platform));
});
```

The above is ok - it creates exchanges as I declared them in the configuration file (fanout exchanges, if that matters). Now the consumer configuration:

```
var options = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>().GetOptions<RabbitMqConsumerOptions>("RabbitMqConsumer");

Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(options.Address);

    foreach (var kvp in options.Endpoints)
    {
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ingest-products", ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = kvp.Value.PrefetchCount;
            ep.BindMessageExchanges = false;

            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(kvp.Value.RetryCount, kvp.Value.RetryInterval));
            ep.Bind("ingest-amazon-products", x => BindForEndpoint(x, kvp.Value.RoutingKey));
            BindExchange(ep, kvp.Value.RoutingKey, kvp.Value.Assembly, kvp.Value.Type);
            ep.ConfigureConsumers(serviceProvider);
        });
    }
});
```

Now, the code above works, but not in the way I intended, as messages without matching routing keys still get delivered to my consumers. I mean - if the `kvp.Value.RoutingKey` configuration value is X, and the producer produces a message with a routing key of Y, the consumer listening for X's will get a Y message. How to fix that?

Comment: Fanout? you should be using direct exchanges if you want to route by RoutingKey to specific endpoint instances. Look at [Sample-Direct](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct) as an example, which you seem to be close but missing that exchange type specification.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - but what code should I use? In the DirectClient you're invoking the `ReceiveEndpoint` method and setting the type inside, but your client is also a receiver of messages and mine is not. Should I do it anyway?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - tbh, I was mostly using this doc: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#routing-key - you don't do anything special on the producer side in the send topology configuration.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - I modified the code so that now the producer is also invoking `ReceiveEndpoint` and it works. Could you please post an answer, I could accept? :)

Comment: Your producer has a receive endpoint? That doesn't seem right, at all. Producers should not be receiving messages, nor configuring queues that other services are using.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson - well, ok. Then how do I configure all the communication so that everything works right? Sample-Direct shows how to use and configure publishing and I can't use that configuration for sending, as there are simply no methods/properties I could use. However if I use the code that's under that link in my comment above, I get a fanout exchange and my routing keys are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting a bounty, I found out that I should use the `Publish` method of the `BusFactoryConfigurator` interface.

Comment: I don't believe you will get a points refund if you delete the question now, or even if you are not allowed to delete the question until the bounty is over. Did you try?